# periodogram and acf do not match

Tags: r, time-series, acf-pacf, spectral-analysis

I'm wondering why my periodogram and my ACF results do not match here. When I look at the ACF, I see there is seasonality every 12 years. Yet, with a periodogram, I get a peak at a frequency of about .25 implying that seasonality occurs every 4 years.

What am I doing wrong here??

The steel and cars time series data was extracted from these sources: [steel](https://datamarket.com/data/set/22yf/monthly-production-of-raw-steel-in-australia-thousand-tonnes-jan-1956-nov-1993#!ds=22yf&display=line) and [cars](https://datamarket.com/data/set/22pi/australia-monthly-production-of-cars-and-station-wagons-sep-1962-sep-1994#!ds=22pi&display=line).

The following is my code:

```
library(imputeTS)
library(forecast)
library(TSA)

steel <- read.csv("~/stat248/monthly-production-of-raw-steel-.csv")
cars <- read.csv("~/stat248/australia-monthly-production-of-.csv")
colnames(cars)[2]='cars'
colnames(steel)[2]='steel'

cars=ts(cars$cars,start=c(1956,1),end=c(1993,11),frequency = 12)
steel=ts(steel$steel,start=c(1956,1),end=c(1993,11),frequency = 12)
cars = na.interpolation(cars)
cars_bc = BoxCox(cars,BoxCox.lambda(cars))
steel_bc = BoxCox(steel,BoxCox.lambda(steel))
cars_bc_hp = hpfilter(cars_bc,freq = 160000,type="lambda")
steel_bc_hp = hpfilter(steel_bc,freq = 160000,type="lambda")

acf(cars_bc_hp$cycle,lag.max=400
periodogram(cars_bc_hp$cycle)
```

[image: ACF of the detrended component of cars]

[image: Periodogram of the detrended component]
But I'm getting this...

Comment: The periodogram that you show also exhibits a peak at a point around 0.08, which is related to a cycle of around 12 years. A smoothed version of the periodogram may be easier to interpret, see for example the function `spectrum`.